# Web config increase php memory limit

Tags: php, memory, web-config

I am taking this error in codeigniter

> Error Number: IMSSP/-59
>
> Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query

I need to increase PHP memory limit.  I am using windows server so if I have to change `.htaccess` file I should convert to `web.config` file.

How can I correct this trouble ?

Comment: Do you mean you are using IIS?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/664034/php-eats-a-lot-of-memory-on-iis

Comment: Definitely. I am using codeigniter and MSSQL server in my project.